# How to initialize a javascript variable using Json String in Asp.net MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-2

I have the following Action method.

```
public ActionResult Action()
{
   var model = new SampleViewModel();
   model.JsonString = ReadJsonStringFromSomewhere();
   return ViewResult(model);
}
```

In my view I have the following method to initialize a javascript variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var jsObject = eval("(" + <%= Model.JsonString %> + ")");
    alert(jsObject); 

</script>
```

The 'jsObject' I get is undefined. What is wrong here. Also is it the best method to initialize a javascript variable with a complex json string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON is literal JavaScript. You don't need the `eval` at all. The following will work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var jsObject = <%= Model.JsonString %>;
    alert(jsObject); 

</script>
```

That said, your `eval` version should still work, albeit more slowly. You don't show your JSON, but it might not be valid.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var jsObject = '<%= Model.JsonString %>';
alert(jsObject);
```

Comment: No, that gives a string, not an object. He wants an object.

Answer (score 1):

I think that looking at the rendered HTML and FireBug could be your best friend.  The code snippet provided by Craig Stuntz looks good, so if it's not working, I would think that the emitted JSON has something wrong with it.

Comment: I'll say!  Your reputation is almost 2k times that of mine! ;)  

But honestly, it seems like the most often forgotten "debugging" technique.  I'm constantly reminding coworkers to do that.